# Can't seem to uninstall Spotify completely?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, uninstall, spotify

I've tried `apt-get remove --purge spotify-client`, but when I try `apt-get update`, I get the following:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease
Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release  file 
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Spotify shouldn't be anywhere on the system, right? I'm fairly new to Linux, so thank you to anyone who can teach me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Please, show us the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list and the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ with their contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem when upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 from Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462778/problem-when-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04-from-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 3):

If you installed it through snap, use

```
sudo snap remove spotify
```